# Not sure how to clean up & use my seemingly difficult parsed JSON response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, json, parsing

Rails 4.2 dev environment

I have a controller `Searches` with:

```
def index
  @search_term = params[:s] || 'shoes'
  @listings = Class_name.for(@search_term)
end
```

a model that the controller uses for the `Class_name` class object & the `for` method used upon the object:

```
class Class_name
include HTTParty

base_uri 'http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?SERVICE-NAME=FindingService&OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByKeywords&SERVICE-VERSION=1.13.0&SECURITY-APPNAME=xxxx&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=JSON&REST-PAYLOAD&GLOBAL-ID=EBAY-US&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=25&paginationInput.pageNumber=1'
format :json

  def self.for term
    get("", query: { keywords: term})["findItemsByKeywordsResponse"]
  end

end
```

and lastly, a view - where I create a table to show the parsed response from eBay's API.

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <th>Image</th>
    <th>Name</th>
</tr>
<% @listings.each do |product| %>
<tr>
    <td><%= image_tag(product["searchResult"][0]["item"][0]["galleryURL"])%></td>
    <td><%= product["searchResult"][0]["item"].sample(25) %></td>
</tr>
    <% end %>
</table>
```

My questions are for the model and for the view.

For the model, I tried to add a `default_params` HTTParty method - to not have my `base_uri` so long and easier to manage - but when I would write:

```
default_params SERVICE-NAME: "FindingService", OPERATION-NAME: "#{operation}" ,etc ,etc
```

it would give me **errors** basically saying **symbols can't be constants "SERVICE-NAME" but the params for the api must be/should be in caps**.

Why can't constants be considered a hash/symbol when they have an assigned value? I guess because they're expected to already have a pre-assigned value by convention?

How would I then assign these values in a safer way than I'm doing now - not being able to use them as symbols? **->>> Answered by Starbelly.**

Also, is there any merit in hiding my App ID considering if people followed a redirect - wouldn't it display the App ID within the URL anyhow? If not, wouldn't they need it to follow a redirect?

What about an affiliate Id instead? I'd surely need to have the affiliate Id stay within the URL of redirecting someone to the traffic'd link to get credit.

Onto the view questions:
This is the part that has been really giving me trouble.

So in the model code, you see the `self.for(term)` method, it takes in the param you give it to query for the keywords param required for a search & it results in a `JSON` formatted table of values named `findItemsByKeywordsResponse` that I want to access.

Searching for a chair,
the beginning code looks like this:

```
   {
findItemsByKeywordsResponse: [
{
ack: [
"Success"
],
version: [
"1.13.0"
],
timestamp: [
"2016-07-11T01:33:40.002Z"
],
searchResult: [
{
@count: "25",
item: [
{
    itemId: [
        "351198621254"
            ],
    title: [
        "Black PU Leather High Back Office Chair Executive Task Ergonomic Computer Desk"
           ],
    globalId: [
        "EBAY-US"
           ],
    subtitle: [
        "Ship from IN & CA ! Delivery in 1-3 Days US 48 States !"
              ],
    primaryCategory: [
        {
        categoryId: [
            "61677"
                    ],
        categoryName: [
            "Chairs"
                      ]
        }
                     ],
    secondaryCategory: [
        {
        categoryId: [
            "54235"
                    ],
        categoryName: [
            "Chairs"
                      ]
        }
                      ],
    galleryURL: [
        "http://thumbs3.ebaystatic.com/m/mBdjVHSC7hWaSBl-4Ku69aA/140.jpg"
                ],
     viewItemURL: [
        "http://www.ebay.com/itm/Black-PU-Leather-High-Back-Office-Chair-Executive-Task-Ergonomic-Computer-Desk-/351198621254"
                  ],
    paymentMethod: [
        "PayPal"
                   ],
    autoPay: [
        "true"
             ],
    postalCode: [
        "91748"
                ],
    location: [
        "Rowland Heights,CA,USA"
              ],
    country: [
        "US"
             ],
    shippingInfo: [
        {
            shippingServiceCost: [
        {
            @currencyId: "USD",
                __value__: "0.0"
        }
                                 ],
    shippingType: [
        "Free"
                  ],
    shipToLocations: [
            "US"
                     ],
    expeditedShipping: [
        "true"
                       ],
    oneDayShippingAvailable: [
        "false"
                             ],
    handlingTime: [
        "0"
                  ]
        }
                  ],
    sellingStatus: [
        {
        currentPrice: [
        {
        @currencyId: "USD",
            __value__: "99.99"
        }
                      ],
    convertedCurrentPrice: [
        {
        @currencyId: "USD",
        __value__: "99.99"
        }
                           ],
    sellingState: [
        "Active"
                  ],
    timeLeft: [
        "P26DT23H9M53S"
              ]
        }
                ],
    listingInfo: [
        {
        bestOfferEnabled: [
            "false"
                 ],
        buyItNowAvailable: [
            "false"
                           ],
        startTime: [
            "2014-10-17T00:43:32.000Z"
                  ],
    endTime: [
        "2016-08-07T00:43:32.000Z"
             ],
    listingType: [
        "FixedPrice"
                 ],
    gift: [
        "false"
          ]
        }
             ],
    returnsAccepted: [
        "true"
                     ],
    condition: [
        {
        conditionId: [
            "1000"
                     ],
        conditionDisplayName: [
            "New"
                              ]
        }
               ],
    isMultiVariationListing: [
        "false"
                             ],
    discountPriceInfo: [
        {
        originalRetailPrice: [
        {
        @currencyId: "USD",
            __value__: "209.99"
        }
                            ],
        pricingTreatment: [
            "STP"
                          ],
        soldOnEbay: [
            "false"
                    ],
        soldOffEbay: [
            "false"
                     ]
        }
                     ],
    topRatedListing: [
        "true"
                     ]
        },
```

After the last comma on the above code it repeats the next array of item. ["item"][1] with the same attributes in the JSON as above.

There is some more code, but all the nesting is similar to this portion.
This code so far is for only one individual item & as seen in the model's base_uri params & view, each page is being paginated with 25 items & 25 items are being sampled to display.

I realise to access this information individually, you must access the item array `["item"][0], ["item"][1],`etc to get to information such as `["title"]`
for each product.

And I have even tested my code using the above way and upon doing so (`product["searchResult"][0]["item"][0]["title"]`) I can put the title value in my table on a per product basis - but it doesn't format and show correctly. 
the actual value shows up from the array as this:

```
["Black PU Leather High Back Office Chair Executive Task Ergonomic Computer Desk"]
```

with the array blocks and quotes around the value and everything - rendering inside the table coded in my view file.

How do I extract the "true" value out of the array/hashes? - getting rid of the array block code and quotes

Also - again - as seen in the model file's base_uri code, the listings are automatically getting paginated at a result of 25 products per page upon a get request.

Knowing this & pre-defining this, how do I iterate over and access the value of all 25 of the `["searchResult"][0]["item"][1..25]` `title` values & `galleryURL` values? & Once again. while getting rid of the `[ ]` and `""` around each value.

The code I am using now, sampling the 25 `["item"]` array values, is basically just rendering the exact code I posted earlier from the `findItemsKeywordsResponse` `JSON` table while I've been trying to figure all of this out.

Help on this will be very very greatly appreciated.

Also - even sampling the 25 `["item"]` array values above, it isn't iterating over any one of the 25. it's rendering all 25 samples in one single row.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" and the linked pages, and "[mcve]". Your question is long. Please reduce it to the bare minimum necessary to explain the problem. Anything beyond that slows help for you as we try to sift through it and make sense of what you wrote. Also, please don't use "Edit" or "Update", instead, incorporate the change into the text as if you put it there in the first place.

Comment: I understand the writing is long, but it's a multi-part question & I've separated the questions into organized chunks.

I think these are fundamentally important concepts to understand & in the case of there being less responses due to it being too read-heavy, those who do respond will be inherently helpful.
Thank you for the info!

Comment: How about indenting the JSON so it's easier to read?

Comment: It is now indented as a replica of the exact JSONView plugin formatted page I receive when I request a get response to the API! Keep in mind - as noted in the original post - the value response is including quotes and array blocks! I.E; the itemId value is literally:

    ([
        "351198621254"
     ])

but without parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question:

Use the hash rocket: `default_params "SERVICE-NAME" => "FindingService", "OPERATION-NAME" => "#{operation}"`

As for the JSON, could you post the full response? It's cut off at the end it seems.

To answer your question about iterating over items, etc. There are multiple ways you could do this, here is one:

```
items = {
      item: [{
        itemId: [
          '351198621254',
        ],
    title: [
      'Black PU Leather High Back Office Chair Executive Task Ergonomic Computer Desk',
    ],
  },
    {
    itemId: [
      '551198621254',
    ],
    title: [
      'Blue PU Leather High Back Office Chair Executive Task Ergonomic Computer Desk',
    ]
    }
  ]
}

def parse_response_item_list(res)
  items = []
  res[:item].each do |item|
    parse_response_item(item) do |parsed|
      items << parsed
    end
  end
  items
end

def parse_response_item(res)
  tidy_result = {}
  if res.is_a? Hash
    res.each_pair do |key,val|
      if val.is_a? String
        tidy_result[key] = val
      else
        parse_response_item(val) do |string|
          tidy_result[key] = string
        end
      end
    end
    yield tidy_result
  elsif res.is_a? Array
    res.each do |e|
      parse_response_item(e) { |r| yield r }
    end
  elsif res.is_a? String
    yield res
  end
  tidy_result
end

result = parse_response_item_list(items)
p result
[
  { 
    :itemId=>"351198621254", 
    :title=>"Black PU Leather High Back Office Chair Executive Task Ergonomic Computer Desk"
  }, 
  { 
    :itemId=>"551198621254", 
    :title=>"Blue PU Leather High Back Office Chair Executive Task Ergonomic Computer Desk"
  }
]
```

Also, note that the response you posted above is not json, it looks like a data dump of a ruby Array.

Comment: Thank you! That slipped right past me.

I've updated the original post with the full response.

Comment: If I were you I would write a chunk of code of to parse the response and stuff all the relevant bits into a hash. You know you're starting with a hash so start off with `response.each_pair do |k,v|`... From there you can inspect each value to see if it's a string or a some type of structure, you can use #is_a? to aid you in this, I would break this parsing routine into a few different methods so you can recurse. Make sense?

Comment: Yes it does. This is a very helpful response & I will get started on your suggestions - but I am confused about a few things..
How would I go about iterating over them knowing that ["item"] is an array of as many of a number as I allow to be paginated with hash values inside of them?
& Upon inspecting each value, if they result as strings, how do i slice off the ([" "]) around each value?

Comment: Thank you a ton for your help starbelly.
I've had similar thoughts as you for the methods but I wasn't exactly sure about how to handle it. You've put me in a great direction.
I think my last question is - in the items hash where you define the key & values "itemId & title" within the item array, how would I go about extracting it without giving it an exact string?
Every time I give the query a search, the item array, title, itemId & galleryURL values will change & I will need to compensate for this factor.

Comment: You mean to say the label 'item' will change? In one query it may be 'foo' and in other it may 'bar'? Even if you query the same endpoint and resource?

Comment: Oops i'm sorry I meant for each index in the item array, ["item"][0], ["item"][1] and so on for each item - the value will change.

item[0]'s title, itemId, & galleryURL are dependent values that will change with every get request

Comment: Hmmm, little confused. If you do something similar to the code I posted in the answer, in your view you can just iterate over the array of hashes. `items.each do { |item| puts item[:title]; puts item[:itemId]; puts item[:galleryURL]; }` I can't imagine ebay is going to design an API where they break backwards compatibility with every request : ) There has to be some degree of certainty about what you're getting in your response. Also note that you can use the technique I showed you to parse the rest of the response into tidy results. You'll just have to modify it to look for certain keys.

Comment: See http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/shopping/docs/CallRef/FindProducts.html#Output if you haven't already, good luck : )

Comment: very true :) So at this point knowing now how to iterate over the array of hashes correctly, I should create a method to send a get request to the page with the query'd keyword(s) that stores the values I need? & then I use the other methods to iterate over the newly stored values?
ie; in your example, you create a pre-defined items hash with stored values but sending a get request to the api the values will change each time & I have to store them?
I'm sorry if i'm just confused ._. you've been a ton of help